# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Estoy pasando un proyecto de vue2 a vue 3, y tras actualizar todo y que el yarn watch no me de errores me aparece esto en consola:

````
    at Module.default (app.js?id=c1e921bb2d946c8b618b3d0fe2308865:367949:42)
    at ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/components/Dialog.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js?id=c1e921bb2d946c8b618b3d0fe2308865:30432:49)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=c1e921bb2d946c8b618b3d0fe2308865:506697:42)
    at ./resources/js/components/Dialog.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js?id=c1e921bb2d946c8b618b3d0fe2308865:379778:208)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=c1e921bb2d946c8b618b3d0fe2308865:506697:42)
    at ./resources/js/components/Dialog.vue (app.js?id=c1e921bb2d946c8b618b3d0fe2308865:367952:93)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=c1e921bb2d946c8b618b3d0fe2308865:506697:42)
    at ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/pages/houses/listHouses/HousesList.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js?id=c1e921bb2d946c8b618b3d0fe2308865:85711:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=c1e921bb2d946c8b618b3d0fe2308865:506697:42)
    at ./resources/js/pages/houses/listHouses/HousesList.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js?id=c1e921bb2d946c8b618b3d0fe2308865:384242:217)```

¿Alguien sabe donde puede estar el fallo? Por mas que busco y miro importaciones y referencias no doy con la solución.
````